# Multiple taxonomies as hierarchy php and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

i have 3 taxonomies for example:

```
Country
City
Person
```

All taxonomies are independent and at the same level, i have 4 posts with different terms:

```
Post 1 => Country: Italy
Post 2 => City: Rome
Post 3 => Person: Mario Rossi
Post 4 => Italy, Rome and Mario Rossi
Post 5 => No Taxonomies
```

Now all that i need to get a return as an hirechial and multidimensional array like this, started from the posts:

```
Array(
      "Italy" => array(
            "Rome" => array(
                  "Mario Rossi" => array(
                        "Post 1" => array(.....),
                        "Post 2" => array(.....),
                        "Post 3" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....)
                  )
                  "No Person" => array(
                        "Post 1" => array(.....),
                        "Post 2" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....)
                  )
            ),
            "No City" => array(
                  "Mario Rossi" => array(
                        "Post 1" => array(.....),
                        "Post 3" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....),
                  ),
                  "No Person" => array(
                        "Post 1" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....)
                  )                  
            )
      )
      "No Nation" => array(
            "Rome" => array(
                  "Mario Rossi" => array(
                        "Post 2" => array(.....),
                        "Post 3" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....),
                  ),
                  "No Person" => array(
                        "Post 2" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....),
                  )
            ),
            "No City" => array(
                  "Mario Rossi" => array(
                        "Post 3" => array(.....),
                        "Post 4" => array(.....),
                  ),
            "No Person" => array(
                    "Post 5" => array(......)
                  )
            )
      )
);
```

How can i do?

Your help are really appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Comment: **Why** do you need it returned as an array like this? Something tells me that you can achieve what you want more easily than this.  Also - you need some sort of "map" or similar to define the relationships between Country, City, and Person.

Comment: Looks like you need a foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Hi @cale_b, can u explain me what do you mean when u talk about "map"? Thx